# LoadableDetachableModel and an Ajax button (Wicket)

Tags: database, forms, wicket

I have a problem similar to the one described by LutherBaker [here](http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/Ajax-and-LoadableDetachableModel-td1885858.html), i.e. the load method of LoadableDetachableModel is called before the onSubmit() method of the Ajax button. Is there a model that works similar to LoadableDetachableModel but is called after the onSubmit method?

My problem: When a form is submitted, I update a record in the database. However, this update is not visible in a drop down list (that is refreshed after the onSubmit() call - it's added to `target`) with a LoadableDetachableModel, because this LDM is loaded before onSubmit() method of the form.

How do I make the changes done in the onSubmit() method visible in the drop down list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it work with a non detachable model? Does the component have the [markup id rendered out](http://wicket.sourceforge.net/apidocs/wicket/Component.html#setOutputMarkupId%28boolean%29)?

Comment: it does work on a model that for every getObject() call looks into the database.

Comment: so to detach the LDM explicitly is not an option for you?

Comment: why? Still it will prevent unnecessary data being stored in the sessions context. I would be fine with having to reload it after I changed the database value. But maybe someone knows a better approach...

Answer (score 0):

A LoadableDetachableModel has a cache, to avoid extra database requests and such.
If the LDM is loaded (it's load() method being called) after the onSubmit event is triggered but before you update the record, then you need to reload you LDM by detaching it, so that it will be reloaded with fresh data when the ajax target is rendered.

So try to call detach() on the model, at the end of the onSubmit() method.

If this doesn't work, then also verify that your database commands are send at the expected moment. For example, if you use some JPA flushmodes, then some database commands may be delayed to the end of the transaction, which can cause the data to be reloaded using a read query before the update query has taken place.